# How do I dynamically set the "required" status of fields in Acrobat?

Tags: javascript, validation, acrobat

I have an Acrobat PDF that a colleague would like some form validation added to beyond the simple options that Acrobat gives you without using javascript. From what I can tell, Javascript will be required to do this. I **think** the behavior should be able to be done via the "Add an Action->MouseDown->Run a Javascript" option found in Properties->Actions of the radio button group.

Basically I have a group of radio buttons with 3 buttons. If buttonA is pressed, I'd like fieldA to be required. If buttonB is pressed, I'd like fieldB to be required. The same for buttonC/fieldC.

I know what my pseudo code is going to look like but I'm having trouble translating it into javascript

```
onSelectionChanged(selection) {
    fieldA.required = false;
    fieldB.required = false;
    fieldC.required = false;

    if (selection == 'A') { fieldA.required = true; }
    if (selection == 'B') { fieldB.required = true; }
    if (selection == 'C') { fieldC.required = true; }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some more digging, here was the eventual solution (placed in the "MouseUp->Run a Javascript" of the radio button group:

```
var f = this.getField("ServiceType");

var ins = this.getField("InstallationDateTime");
var rem = this.getField("RemovalDateTime");
var ser = this.getField("ServiceRequestDateTime");

console.println(f.value);

ins.required = false;
rem.required = false;
ser.required = false;

if (f.value === "Install") {
    ins.required = true;       
}
if (f.value === "Removal") {
    rem.required = true;       
}
if (f.value === "Service") {
    ser.required = true;       
}
```

Pretty easy all things considered, finding the [following](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/10/Acrobat10_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=Acrobat_SDK_whats_new.14.7.html&accessible=true) was really nice for debugging:

```
f = this.getField("myField");

for ( var i in f ) {
    try {
        if ( typeof f[i] != "function" ) {    // Do not list field methods
            console.println( i + ":" + f[i] ) 
        }
    } catch(e) {
    }           // An exception occurs when we get a property that does not apply to this field type.
}
```